# Fullcalendar - How to add time of the day in week view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Default weekview is like this one, no time of the day on left side:

http://fullcalendar.io/views/basicWeek/

but I'd like to make the view this way, with time of the day on left side:

http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.3.1/demos/agenda-views.html

click 'week' on upper button panel to see it.

How do I configure it to make it looks like this way?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to change your vie to agendaWeek  [Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/) . you can use [changeView function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/changeView/)

Comment: Things may have changed, I ended up using the timeGrid plugin to get this to work with timeGridWeek for the view - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `defaultView` property. This sets, as specified [in the docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/defaultView/), the initial view when the calendar loads. The specific view you want is `agendaWeek` ([list of available views](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/)).

So when you initialize your calendar, you'll put `defaultView: 'agendaWeek'`.

Example:

```js
$('#fullCal').fullCalendar({
  events: [{
    title: 'Random Event 1',
    start: moment().add(-4, 'h'),
    end: moment().add(-2, 'h'),
    allDay: false
  }, {
    title: 'Random Event 2',
    start: moment().add(1, 'h'),
    end: moment().add(2, 'h'),
    allDay: false
  }, {
    title: 'Random Event 3',
    start: moment().add(6, 'h'),
    end: moment().add(8, 'h'),
    allDay: false
  }],
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'prev title next today',
    right: ''
  },
  timezone: 'local',
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek' /* this is the line you need */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

<div id="fullCal"></div>
```